# Publish my MVC3 site on localhost

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I am trying to publish my mvc web site on the localhost through visual studio but the problem is when i browse to the the localhost in the browser it gives me a directory listing page. here is the screen shot of publish dialogue. Can somebody please guide me through the process i have been searching for the whole day but couldn't get it to work

[image]

here id the global.ascx

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute("Facebook",
                           "XdReceiver",
                           new { controller = "Account", action = "XdReceiver" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try navigating to `http://localhost/Rental`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes it gives me a 404

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a requirement to use WebDeploy for your publish? If not, you could create a directory and point IIS to that directory and change your publish method to File System.

IMO, WebDeploy is overkill for localhost deployments if you're using it simply for testing. WebDeploy becomes very useful for network deployments since it compares the contents of the directories and maintains which files have been updated and which ones have not.

Comment: i created an empty website pointed it to wwwroot and published it and i get the directory listing page, why i can get the home page, what could i be missing

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the "Mark as IIS application on destination" option.
Also, try publishing to `Default Web Site/Rental` and accessing it as `http://localhost/Rental`.

If you installed IIS after installing .NET, did you run `aspnet_regiis -i`? And could you please post your Global.asax file with MVC routes?

Answer (score 1):

just create a empty site using IIS. and then publish the site in visual studio using the `File System` publish method.

Comment: run the visual studio as Administrator